# When user press button show datepicker view and select date and then display as button title and further close datepicker view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uibutton, uidatepicker

I wrote this code. but not worlking...

Yes NSLog is saw proper date.

Datepicker also saw and select date. But when i select date nothing to changes on my button title and datepicker remain on the screen. I want hide also when user selected date...

Actually i display datepicker view when user press button and then select date and set title to button and release picker view.
I use ios 5...

```
[datePicker setHidden:NO];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self.datePicker date]];

   NSLog(@"\n"
      "theDate: |%@| \n"
       , dateString);
[self.DOBbutton setTitle:dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This question is hard to understand. What is not working? Is it the datePicker that is not showing?

Comment: in NSLog it prints proper or not?

Comment: I tried your code and it is working. I think yo need to edit your post and add the code you have to release the picker view and the action connected to the button.

Comment: DOBbutton is in .xib or programatically?

Answer (score 4):

in your button action write this code

```
UIActionSheet *dateActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
        [dateActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
        [dateActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [dateActionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 383)];
        UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 100, 116)];
        dp.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
//        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *eventDate = dp.date;
        NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [timeFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
        [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        timeString = [timeFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
        [ dp addTarget: self action:
         @selector(dateChanged:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged
         ];


        [ self.view addSubview: dp ];

     //   txtProposeTime.font = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 9.0 ];
     //   txtProposeTime.textColor = [ UIColor blackColor ];

        txtProposeTime.text = timeString;

        [dp setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];
        [dateActionSheet addSubview:dp];
```

Outside button write this code

```
-(void) dateChanged: (id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *control = (UIDatePicker *) sender;
    control.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *eventDate = control.date;
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [timeFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
    txtMeetingDate.text=dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

replace  it

```
    [self.DOBbutton setTitle:dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

with

```
   DOBbutton.titleLabel.text =dateString;
```

and make sure button is connected with your xib or not

Comment: please give your date picker code,is it in Xib or programmatically ?

Comment: - (IBAction)selectDOB:(id)sender {
    
    
    [datePicker setHidden:NO];
    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self.datePicker date]];
    
    NSLog(@"\n"
          "theDate: |%@| \n"
           , dateString);
    [self.DOBbutton setTitle:dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [datePicker setHidden:YES];
    
    //DOBbutton.titleLabel.text=dateString;
    
    
    
}

Comment: set datePicker.hidden=YES;

Comment: set in viewdidload  [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];   and in this valueChanged method write hidden=YES

Answer (score 0):

Set button with title Done and when user select Done at that time called bellow method...

```
-(IBAction)btnDone_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    NSString *dateString =[[yourDatePicker date] stringFromDateWithFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [yourButton setTitle:dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourDatePicker setHidden:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and this is my custome method which useful for change the format of Date and convert it to string..

```
-(NSString*)stringFromDateWithFormat:(NSString*)strDateFormat{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     //[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:strDateFormat];
    NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:self];
    [formatter release];
    return str;
}
```