# how to implement date picker on button click in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, forms, uidatepicker

I am building an iOS app.I am using storyboards to build the screens and i have made a form which contain some fields like Name,Date,min and max.

I am facing an problem that is not able to implement date picker on button click and when user select the date,date picker hide,want to display selected date in a label.

I googled but could not find a good tutorial or library.
I want to show only days and date in picker.

Comment: Try this :
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030559/when-user-press-button-show-datepicker-view-and-select-date-and-then-display-as

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)datePickerBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,10, 50)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(labelTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
    rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(save:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;       
}

-(void)labelTitle:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat  stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    //assign text to label
    label.text=str; 
}

-(void)save:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    [datePicker removeFromSuperview];       
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)date:(id)sender {
    datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 300)];
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datepicker.hidden = NO;
    datepicker.date = [NSDate date];

    [datepicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(labelChange:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datepicker]; //this can set value of selected date to your label change according to your condition


       NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"M-d-yyyy"]; // from here u can change format.. 
    _selectedDate.text = [df stringFromDate:datepicker.date];
}

- (void)labelChange:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"M-d-yyyy"];
    _selectedDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [df stringFromDate:datepicker.date]];
    [datepicker removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use various controls form this

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=datepicker

Answer (score 2):

Add hidden textfield view and configure the date picker.

```
[self.xTextFeild setInputView:_datePicker];
```

Then 
When ever you want call below code.

```
[self.xTextFeild becomeFirstResponder];
```

`