# Show KeyBoard on pressing button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a bell button for setting date and time for alarm. I am having trouble in showing the `DatePickerView` as keyboard. Is there any way to show keyboard on button pressed, 
please help..

Comment: share your code you have tried.

Comment: Actually I have tried with textView but have got no idea for a button.

Comment: Your should provide inputView for your text view(or text field).Please google a tutorial for that.

Comment: It's not a keyboard you want to show - always try to name your question well :) Also, please google and search for the answer before posting on here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796302/how-to-implement-date-picker-on-button-click-in-ios

Comment: Actually the idea was if could show keyboard then i can change it as per my need i.e. datepickerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**EDIT**

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) 
{
    YOUR_TEXTFIELD.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Hope this helps